# Errors while opening an Excel file created by Open XML

Tags: xml, excel, openxml

I have started using Open XML to create an Excel file in order to add some data to it. The example file I have included is modified version of an example I found online. It creates the excel file but when I try to open it, it gives me three errors. I suspect the last two errors are due to adding **StyleIndex** for a heading cell but the first error has recently showing up when I open any Excel file.

1- Cannot use object linking and embedding.

2- Excel found unreadable content in 'SheetPInfo.xlsx'.Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

3-Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content. 
Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet.xml part

I also get the data/array in the file after closing the last error message but the StyleIndex (bigger font) does not appear in the heading cell 'Last Name'.

What could have been wrong? As I searched online, the order of lines are very important for Excel so I thought maybe my StyleIndex related lines are in wrong places.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet
Public Class TestEcel10
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private mFileName As String = "SheetPInfo.xlsx"
    Private mFileLocation As String = "c:\Contracts\" & mFileName
    Private newSpreadSheet As SpreadsheetDocument

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
    Private Sub btnExportToExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExportToExcel.Click

        Dim wsp As WorksheetPart = Spreadsheet_Create()

        Dim PInfoArr(2, 3) As String
        PInfoArr(0, 0) = "Frank"
        PInfoArr(0, 1) = "Baker"
        PInfoArr(0, 2) = "2/18/1977"
        PInfoArr(0, 3) = "Frank"

        PInfoArr(1, 0) = "William"
        PInfoArr(1, 1) = "Cook"
        PInfoArr(1, 2) = "2/18/1987"
        PInfoArr(1, 3) = "Bill"

        PInfoArr(2, 0) = "Nancy"
        PInfoArr(2, 1) = "Williams"
        PInfoArr(2, 2) = "2/18/1973"
        PInfoArr(2, 3) = "Nancy"

        InsertText(wsp, PInfoArr)
        Spreadsheet_Close()
    End Sub   'End of btnExportToExcel_Click Sub

    Private Function Spreadsheet_Create() As WorksheetPart
        'Delete the file if exists
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(mFileLocation) Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(mFileLocation)
        End If

        'Create spreadsheet
        newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(mFileLocation, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook)

        'Add WorkbookPart & Workbook
        Dim newWorkbookPart As WorkbookPart = newSpreadSheet.AddWorkbookPart
        newWorkbookPart.Workbook = New Workbook()

        'Add Worksheet
        Return InsertWorksheet(newSpreadSheet.WorkbookPart)
    End Function   'End of Spreadsheet_Create function

    Private Sub Spreadsheet_Close()
        newSpreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save()
        newSpreadSheet.Close()
    End Sub   'End of Spreadsheet_Close sub

    Public Sub InsertText(ByVal wsp As WorksheetPart, ByVal PInfoArray As String(,))
        ' Get the SharedStringTablePart. If it does not exist, create a new one.
        Dim shareStringPart As SharedStringTablePart
        If (newSpreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType(Of SharedStringTablePart).Count() > 0) Then
            shareStringPart = newSpreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType(Of SharedStringTablePart).First()
        Else
            shareStringPart = newSpreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart(Of SharedStringTablePart)()
        End If

        Dim index As Integer = 0
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        Dim cell As Cell

        'Inserting column headings:

        ' Insert the text into the SharedStringTablePart.
        index = InsertSharedStringItem("First Name", shareStringPart)
        ' Insert cell A1 into the new worksheet.
        cell = InsertCellInWorksheet("A", 1, wsp)
        ' Set the value of cell A1.
        cell.CellValue = New CellValue(index.ToString)
        cell.DataType = New EnumValue(Of CellValues)(CellValues.SharedString)

        ' Insert the text into the SharedStringTablePart.
        index = InsertSharedStringItem("Last Name", shareStringPart)
        Dim styleIndex As UInt32Value = Convert.ToInt32("36")
        ' Insert cell A1 into the new worksheet.
        cell = InsertCellInWorksheet("B", 1, wsp)
        ' Set the value of cell A1.
        cell.CellValue = New CellValue(index.ToString)
        cell.StyleIndex = styleIndex
        cell.DataType = New EnumValue(Of CellValues)(CellValues.SharedString)

        ' Insert the text into the SharedStringTablePart.
        index = InsertSharedStringItem("Birth Date", shareStringPart)
        ' Insert cell A1 into the new worksheet.
        cell = InsertCellInWorksheet("C", 1, wsp)
        ' Set the value of cell A1.
        cell.CellValue = New CellValue(index.ToString)
        cell.DataType = New EnumValue(Of CellValues)(CellValues.SharedString)

        ' Insert the text into the SharedStringTablePart.
        index = InsertSharedStringItem("Nick Name", shareStringPart)
        ' Insert cell A1 into the new worksheet.
        cell = InsertCellInWorksheet("D", 1, wsp)
        ' Set the value of cell A1.
        cell.CellValue = New CellValue(index.ToString)
        cell.DataType = New EnumValue(Of CellValues)(CellValues.SharedString)

        'For column data we start from index 2 and increase it as we go to the next row
        Dim Rowindex As Integer = 2
        Dim ColumnLetter As String = "A"

        'Inserting column data:
        For i = 0 To UBound(PInfoArray, 1)

            For j = 0 To UBound(PInfoArray, 2)

                ' Insert the text into the SharedStringTablePart.
                index = InsertSharedStringItem(PInfoArray(i, j), shareStringPart)
                'Set the 
                If j = 0 Then
                    ColumnLetter = "A"
                ElseIf j = 1 Then
                    ColumnLetter = "B"
                ElseIf j = 2 Then
                    ColumnLetter = "C"
                ElseIf j = 3 Then
                    ColumnLetter = "D"
                End If
                ' Insert cell A1 into the new worksheet.
                cell = InsertCellInWorksheet(ColumnLetter, Rowindex, wsp)
                ' Set the value of cell A1.
                cell.CellValue = New CellValue(index.ToString)
                cell.DataType = New EnumValue(Of CellValues)(CellValues.SharedString)

                If ColumnLetter = "D" Then
                    Rowindex = Rowindex + 1
                End If
            Next
        Next

        ' Save the new worksheet.
        wsp.Worksheet.Save()
    End Sub   'End of InsertText sub

    ' Given text and a SharedStringTablePart, creates a SharedStringItem with the specified text
    ' and inserts it into the SharedStringTablePart. If the item already exists, returns its index.
    Private Function InsertSharedStringItem(ByVal text As String, ByVal shareStringPart As SharedStringTablePart) As Integer
        'If the part does not contain a SharedStringTable, create one
        If (shareStringPart.SharedStringTable Is Nothing) Then
            shareStringPart.SharedStringTable = New SharedStringTable
        End If

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        'Iterate through all the items in the SharedStringTable. If the text already exists, return its index
        For Each item As SharedStringItem In shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.Elements(Of SharedStringItem)()
            If (item.InnerText = text) Then
                Return i
            End If
            i = (i + 1)
        Next

        'The text does not exist in the part. Create the SharedStringItem and return its index
        shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.AppendChild(New SharedStringItem(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Text(text)))
        shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.Save()
        Return i
    End Function   'End of InsertSharedStringItem function

    'Given a WorkbookPart, inserts a new worksheet.
    Private Function InsertWorksheet(ByVal workbookPart As WorkbookPart) As WorksheetPart

        ' Add a new worksheet part to the workbook.
        Dim newWorksheetPart As WorksheetPart = _
                       workbookPart.AddNewPart(Of WorksheetPart)()
        newWorksheetPart.Worksheet = New Worksheet(New SheetData)
        newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save()

        'Get a unique ID for the new worksheet
        Dim sheetId As UInteger = 1
        Dim sheets As New Sheets
        If newSpreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild(Of Sheets)() IsNot Nothing Then
            sheets = newSpreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild(Of Sheets)()
            'Not sure if this check is required, possible an hanger-on from previous attempts
            If (sheets.Elements(Of Sheet).Count > 0) Then
                sheetId = sheets.Elements(Of Sheet).Select(Function(s) s.SheetId.Value).Max + 1
            End If
        End If

        Dim relationshipId As String = _
                       newSpreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart)
        Dim sheetName As String = ("Sheet" + sheetId.ToString())

        ' Add the new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
        Dim sheet As Sheet = New Sheet
        sheet.Id = relationshipId
        sheet.SheetId = sheetId
        sheet.Name = sheetName
        sheets.Append(sheet)
        If newSpreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild(Of Sheets)() Is Nothing Then
            newSpreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(Of Sheets)(sheets)
        End If
        workbookPart.Workbook.Save()

        Return newWorksheetPart

    End Function   'End of InsertWorksheet function

    ' Given a column name, a row index, and a WorksheetPart, inserts a cell into the worksheet.
    ' If the cell already exists, return it.
    Private Function InsertCellInWorksheet(ByVal columnName As String, ByVal rowIndex As UInteger, ByVal wsp As WorksheetPart) As Cell
        Dim worksheet As Worksheet = wsp.Worksheet
        Dim sheetData As SheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild(Of SheetData)()
        Dim cellReference As String = (columnName + rowIndex.ToString())
        ' If the worksheet does not contain a row with the specified row index, insert one.
        Dim row As Row
        If (sheetData.Elements(Of Row).Where(Function(r) r.RowIndex.Value = rowIndex).Count() <> 0) Then
            row = sheetData.Elements(Of Row).Where(Function(r) r.RowIndex.Value = rowIndex).First()
        Else
            row = New Row()
            row.RowIndex = rowIndex
            sheetData.Append(row)
        End If
        ' If there is not a cell with the specified column name, insert one.
        If (row.Elements(Of Cell).Where(Function(c) c.CellReference.Value = columnName + rowIndex.ToString()).Count() > 0) Then
            Return row.Elements(Of Cell).Where(Function(c) c.CellReference.Value = cellReference).First()
        Else
            ' Cells must be in sequential order according to CellReference. Determine where to insert the new cell.
            Dim refCell As Cell = Nothing
            For Each cell As Cell In row.Elements(Of Cell)()
                If (String.Compare(cell.CellReference.Value, cellReference, True) > 0) Then
                    refCell = cell
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            Dim newCell As Cell = New Cell
            newCell.CellReference = cellReference

            row.InsertBefore(newCell, refCell)
            worksheet.Save()
            Return newCell
        End If
    End Function   'End of InsertCellInWorksheet function
```

Comment: For the first error, I did try several ways suggested online but none worked only the one that I did not pay attention to it was my answer! Go to start/run/DCOMCNFG/component Services/Computers/My computer/DCOM config/Microsoft Excel Application/Properties/Identity tab, then check the 'The launching user'. The credit this time goes to this website: http://vinforsolutions.blogspot.com/2013/04/cannot-use-object-linking-and-embedding.html It is interesting that no other changes in Security tab would remove the first error but people keep suggesting them.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution to have my data into an Excel file without having any error! I downloaded the .zip file from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/765068/Complete-Open-XML-Spreadsheet-in-VB
and since its Visual Studio version was not the same as mine, I had to copy its openXMLExcelCreator class from the downloaded folder and paste it into my project. Then I added its 'doStuff' sub to my webpage with a different name and modified it to show headings I want and data from a database into the cells. I also managed to change the background of heading row and alternative rows for easy search.